# The most efficient way to compare two dictionaries, verifying dict_2 is a complete subset of dict_1, and return all values of dict_2 which are less?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, api, dictionary

I'm working on a data pipeline that will pull data from online and store it in MongoDB. To manage the process, I've developed two dictionaries; request_totals and mongo_totals. mongo_totals will contain a key for each container in the Mongo database, along with a value for the max(id) that container contains. request_totals has a key for each category data can be pulled from, along with a value for the max(id) of that category. If MongoDB is fully updated, these who dictionaries would be identical.

I've developed code that runs, but I can't shake the feeling that I'm not really being efficient here. I hope that someone can share some tips on how to better write this:

```
def compare(request_totals, mongo_totals):
    outdated = dict()
    
    # Verifies MongoDB contains no unique collections
    if request_totals | mongo_totals != request_totals:
        raise AttributeError('mongo_totals does not appear to be a subset of request_totals')
        
    sharedKeys = set(request_totals.keys()).intersection(mongo_totals.keys())
    unsharedKeys = set(request_totals) - set(mongo_totals)
    
    # Updates outdated dict with outdated key-value pairs representing MongoDB collections
    for key in sharedKeys:
        if request_totals[key] > mongo_totals[key]:
            outdated.update({key : mongo_totals[key]})
        elif request_totals[key] < mongo_totals[key]:
            raise AttributeError(
                f'mongo_total for {key}: {mongo_totals[key]} exceeds request_totals for {key}: {request_totals[key]}')
    
    return outdated|dict.fromkeys(unsharedKeys, 0)

compare(request_totals, mongo_totals)
```

The returned dictionary has key:value pairs that maybe used in the following way; Query the API using the key, and offset the records by the key's value. This way, it allows me to keep  the database updated. Is there a more efficient way to handle this comparison?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/seperman/deepdiff

Comment: @Adam Thanks, I've never heard of that library before!